Is it possible to have two normally open circuits and use one switch to close one or the other (never both at once for my purposes)?
Basically I'm wondering what the type of switch I need would be called, but I'm looking to have one open and one closed circuit at all times - the output destination is NOT the same. These are completely different circuits.
My two completely independent circuits will be battery to load, OR solar panel to battery; don't wish to do pass thru charging, or put another way, I'm not wanting to attempt to energize this bqttery while simultaneously draining it. This is a power tool battery and in the wild, there's no way such a thing could occir, as it would either be on a charger or on the tool. So it seems not wise to attempt pass thru.
But now you can see why I want such a switch, to kind of dummy proof it...that way I never forget to turn off my solar before using the battery, etc.

Does the battery have separate terminals for charging and usage or just one pair of terminals?

Most modern battery chargers will do the right thing, you don't have to police them like this. Read your manual before over complicating it.  And if you can use pass through you'll be more likely to have a full battery when you need it at night.

The kind of switch you want is a DPDT (Double Pole, Double Throw) switch, optionally with middle position.
Double Pole means that one rocker or lever operates on 2 electrical switches. You want this to switch both the + and - terminals of the battery at the same time to the correct circuit.
Double Throw means that the switch can make an electrical connection to two sides. If the switch also has a middle position, then it has a (stable) position where nothing is connected.

Note that the switch should be rated for the current drawn by the tool, which may not be specified in a helpful way, and anyway the startup current might be higher - it is for a lot of motors, but a variable speed trigger will act as a soft start

DP is not two circuits but rather two wires. Which is what you want - i.e., in AC it would be hot and neutral or in DC + and -. DT is what gets you two circuits. An SPDT would only switch one wire, which is the way a "3-way switch" works, but you need to switch 2 wires, so DPDT.

make sure that the switch is break before make type

you only need to switch one wire to open a circuit

@Jasen In general, that is true. However, I would be a bit concerned here about how this circuit actually works, so switching both wires makes a lot of sense to me.

Yes, use a relay which has two outputs ie 5 terminals.
Either one can be live.
The relay has the advantage over a switch that it can handle more current, be closer to the power source & load so reducing the heavier cable needed.
However, if you connect the panels to the battery with a charge controller, then you can still supply the load and charge the battery at the same time so good use of daylight.

An on-off-on SPDT switch can do what you ask

two normally open circuits and use one switch to close one or the other

If you don't want a feature where you can have both turned off at the same time then a regular SPDT will work.

That won't work for the question above. It states "the output destination is NOT the same. These are completely different circuits.", therefore it needs two 'poles', hence DPDT as other answers suggest.

you are inferring something that s not explicitly stated   "are" does not mean "must be" and "different" does not mean "isolated"

SPDT sufficient.  The switched terminal goes to the battery, and one of the others goes to the solar charger, and the other goes to the tool.  Thus the battery connects to either the charger or the tool, and never both.

Add a relay to each circuit. Then use a SPDT switch to energize one relay or the other. You can make the control wiring low voltage to match the relays coil voltage required. Your middle terminal on your switch can be full time powered with your low voltage positive. The remaining 2 terminals wire one terminal to one relay and one terminal to the other relay. Wire your negative to one side of both relay coils.
